# Rancid err: failed router manufacturer: Permission Denied

Tags: linux, configuration, rancid

I'm having some trouble with my initial Rancid set up for my network config backups.

I am at the phase where I am attempting to use the `rancid-run` command to test. When the script completes, I will receive one of the following messages in the log entries:

`sh: /usr/local/rancid/bin/rancid-fe: /root/localperl/bin/perl: Bad interpreter: Permission Denied`

or

`exec(rancid -t cisco) failed router manufacturer: Permission Denied`

I did some research regarding the first error message and I found answers relating to the perl path inside of the rancid-fe scripts and other rancid scrips in the bin folder. The path `#!/root/localperl/bin/perl` was at the top of the "rancid-fe" script and a few other rancid scripts. Apparently this is not the correct path for perl (or the fact that it is in the root home prevents the rancid user from accessing it).

I modified that shebang to `#!/usr/bin/perl` in rancid-fe and that is when the second error began appearing inside of the generated log files. I am not entirely sure what "permissions" the error messages are referring to or how perl interacts with rancid. This is my first time dealing with rancid. I would like some help in fixing this issue or understanding the relationship between perl, rancid, and the error message so that I may move forward in troubleshooting.

I could not find any resources or insight into the second error, thus the thread title. Apologies if I missed anything or repeated an already answered question.

Additional Context:
Rancid version 3.9,
CentOS 6.9,
updated Perl 5.28.1 (installed from source),

Comment: Why did you put in `/usr/bin/perl` instead of the path to your locally compiled perl?

Comment: One of the solutions I found relating to the issue seemed to suggest the local path was incorrect. I modified the script to see if that was the case. Either way, I still get a permission based error.